# How can I get the nresult in ascending & dscending

Tags: java

```
package bucky;
import java.util.*;
public class apple {

    public static void main(String args[]){

       ArrayList<Integer>numbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();

       for(int x=0; x<49; x++){

          numbers.add(x+1);

          Collections.shuffle(numbers);
       }

           for(int y=0; y<6; y++){

          System.out.println(numbers.get(y));
       }
    }
}
```

How can I get the nresult in ascending & dscending ?

Comment: You will need to sort your list.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your numbers list like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class SortingNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 1; i <= 49; i++) {
            numbers.add(i);
        }

        Collections.sort(numbers, Comparator.reverseOrder());

        for(Integer i : numbers) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        Collections.sort(numbers, Comparator.naturalOrder());

        for(Integer i : numbers) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```

**Note**: Please write class names with capital letter!

Answer (score 0):

Create yourself a comparator if your list is not produced in a sequence.

i.e

```
    list.add(5);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(7);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(1);


public class MyIntComparable implements Comparator<Integer>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
       return (o1>o2 ? -1 : (o1==o2 ? 0 : 1));
    }
}
```

Collections.sort(list, new MyIntComparable());

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, you can sort your numbers like this using Lambda expressions.

```
package bucky;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Apple {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int x=0; x<49; x++){
            numbers.add(x+1);
            Collections.shuffle(numbers);
        }

        // sort in ascending order
        Collections.sort(numbers, (Integer p1, Integer p2) -> p1.compareTo(p2));

        // sort in descending order
        Collections.sort(numbers, (Integer p1,  Integer p2) -> p2.compareTo(p1));

        for(int y=0; y<6; y++){
            System.out.println(numbers.get(y));
        }
    }
}
```